# Why did Gretel not get eaten?

Tags: plot-explanation, gretel-and-hansel

In *Gretel and Hansel (2020)*, the witch spends the movie trying to explain to Gretel that she has powers, that Gretel is like the witch. She says they come from the same rotten material. The entire dialog made me think it was because Gretel was female and females inherently have powers.

But, we see that there are plenty of girls among the children that the witch has eaten. So did the witch not eat Gretel because she had powers and the other girls did not, or would the witch have eaten Gretel for her refusal to eat Hansel and become what the witch wanted?